# Lower bound for sumset in discrete cube

Tags: additive-combinatorics, sumsets

Suppose $A\subset\{0,1\}^d$ for some $d\geq 1$. Then how large must $A+A=\{a+b:a,b\in A\}$ be?

Comment: $|A+A|$ can be as small as $0$ (if $A=\emptyset$), and $|A+A|/|A|$ can be as small as $1$ (if $A$ is a singleton). You should be more specific with your question!

Comment: You might also want to clarify if addition is in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb F_2$.